# CSS style time_ago_in_words rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, styles, helpermethods

I was wondering what would be the best solution for customising the rails helper: time_ago_in_words, so that I could do things like:

```
    <span class="one">4</span>
    <span class="two">hours</span>
    <span class="three">ago</span>
```

or what the layout looks like by default?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a helper that splits the result of time_ago_in_words on spaces and returns the array of words.  Then you can format them however you want.

Comment: That's a good idea, I just wonder if I might need something even more customizable as I want to remove the 'about' and also display a date (21 Jan 2011) after a year has passed instead of 'about one year ago', but I will accept your answer in relevance to the question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the method `time_ago_in_words`, you can use [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words), which accepts locale in the option array: create a new locale where you can define "hours" with "hours", etc... and give it to `distance_of_time_in_words`. It should work, but I'm not sure how will be handled the HTML tags.